# possibility of splitting an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering how arrays work down at the binary level because I'm trying to think of a way to split them up; meaning take an array and make it into a linked list and I'm not talking about turning an array into a linked list (copying, old array into new...)I'm saying is there anyway possible to release the data in an array from one another.

Comment: You can move objects from one collection to another without recreating them. It's easiest in C++11 with [rvalue references](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: @David: if he's looking "at the binary level," then he's not dealing with objects or anything that move semantics (which is just an optimized copy) will deal with.

Comment: @NicolBolas: He is because he can just use a level of indirection. That way he can "move" the object from one collection to another without having to move the actual binary data that contains the object's data. This is what rvalue references allow.

Comment: @David: That's *not what he's asking for.* He wants to take a block of memory as an array and magic it into a linked list. He is not looking for move semantics. He doesn't want "a level of indirection". He wants to say, "this array is now a linked list."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't release memory of arbitrary elements in an array, because it's continuous allocated. However it is possible to release the tail, by `realloc`.

Comment: He doesn't want to release it though, he wants to transfer it to another collection. "*is there anyway possible to release the data in an array from one another*" He's looking to *move* objects, not free them.

Comment: @David Schwartz no I want to release it.

Comment: @healix: Then why did you say you wanted to turn it into a linked list? I now have no idea what you're actually asking.

Comment: It's hard to explain I know. I was thinking about it today and I'm referring to the glue that holds the array together whatever that may be

Comment: There's no "glue". Elements of the array are aligned immediately next to one another in memory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I meant give it the same structure as a linked list instead of going through the work of changing an array into a linked list or any data struct for that matter

Comment: @GregHewgill Yeah, I know. was just thinking about it

Comment: @healix The contiguous memory layout of array ensures you can random access in constant time, giving up the flexibility to remove any element in constant time. However with stl containers you can manipulate either structure with similar interface, such as inserting and deleting. Is that what you want?

Comment: @FamZheng No but thanks. I know about data structures in c++ but was just thinking how an array is like a glued together linked list so if that's true then could there be a way to separate the pieces of the array. More theory than anything I guess

Comment: @healix: Right, so you don't want to release them, you want to move them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you can pretty much do anything with an array that you would do with any other contiguous chunk of memory. For example, you could "split" an array (really just point into parts of it) like this:

```
int A[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *part1 = A;
int *part2 = A + 3;

// part1[0] == 0
// part1[1] == 1
// part1[2] == 2
// part2[0] == 3;
// part2[1] == 4;
// part2[2] == 5;
```

When you do stuff like this, you have to carefully make sure that you don't run outside the bounds of the array and cause undefined behavior. A much better approach for almost all cases is to simply use the standard containers and algorithms provided by the C++ standard library.

Comment: Now could you add next pointers to that and make it into a linked list? But real interesting though